# Why web app name with leading slash added to static files path?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tomcat, playframework

I have a web application which is running on Tomcat server in Windows, but now I want to move to Linux. So I have changed all required things and have deployed war file on Tomcat server using Linux. After running tomcat my application works fine but the assets (stylesheets,javascripts and images) are not loading.

I put these assets inside web apps folder. Do I need to set any path?

In my routes file:

```
GET     /SRSFiles/*file            controllers.Assets.at(path="/webapps", file)//for tomcat
#GET     /assets/*file             controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)//for play
```

In main scala page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/theme.css")">
<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/common.js")"></script>
```

Comment: Deployment of war to Tomcat on either OS should be the same. The paths to the resources should be the same independent of OS. Can you get to the images, etc, by going directly to their URL? What URL are you using for example? Would need to see your project structure and routing info.

Comment: But if i place srsmobile folder outside webapps everything works fine.

Comment: /SRSMOBILE  is not added to my assets path in that case

Comment: I would say that /webapps would be incorrect for Tomcat. Your web resides under that location. Unless you have a webapps folder under your specific web folder?

Comment: Please tell why /SRSMOBILE  is added to my static files path if static files are placed in webapps folder.here SRSMOBILE is my web app name.

Comment: why web app name added to assets  path in after deployed in tomcat server?

Comment: Each web in Tomcat is deployed under the root by its web app name. So after you deploy SRSMOBILE to Tomcat, then you'll have to access it via http://hostname/SRSMOBILE. To access an image, for example, then you would access it via "/SRSMOBILE/assets/images/01.jpg" (using full absolute path), provided you have that image in that path under your SRSMOBILE web app folder. Make sense?